# Given a list of named doubles, return the name of the variable with the lowest value

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, list

```
// Method for identifying ingredient with lowest inventory.
void OrderNext()
{
    double ingredient1 = amount1  // doubles are needed as ingredients are used as fragments.
    double ingredient2 = amount2
    double ingredient3 = amount3
    double ingredient4 = amount4

    List<double> ingredientAmounts  = new List<double>  //puts doubles into a list for sorting.
    {
        ingredient 1,
        ingredient 2,
        ingredient 3,
        ingredient 4 
    };

    double orderValue= ingredientAmounts.Min(); //This gets the ingredient with the lowest level

    string orderId = ??? // this is where I get lost.  
}
```

Additional information:

- doubles are required.
- the ingredient list is tentative (currently I'm working with 10 ingredients from several lists)
- I am using Visual Studio Community: C#:  and this is in a working WPF I wrote that I'm attempting to improve.

The goal is to determine which ingredient will run out first and by how much. As you can see, I can get the value but not the name.

Comment: A specification is not a _question_. You've explained (sort of) what the code should do. But, what is it that _you need help with_? What have you tried? What happened when you tried that? How is that different from what you want? Please make sure you've included a good [mcve] that helps illustrates all of this. If this is a homework assignment, be clear about what the constraints are here. Did your teacher really expect you to use LINQ (i.e. the `Min()` method)? When you write "name of the variable" do you really mean that the values must be stored in one variable per value?

Comment: Your code won't compile.

Comment: not related to your problem: consider using decimal instead of double: sums and comparisons happens to be weird with double. 0.3d + 0.7d == 1.0d? I would not bet on it

Comment: Thank you.  I will reassess and return with a better question.  I'm assuming my question got edited because I am clueless to the format I should use. In the meantime, are you able to see the unedited question?

Comment: You can click the link that reads [edited 19 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48271247/revisions), right at the bottom of your post, to see the entire history of the post. (Of course, it may or may not say _"19 hours ago"_ by the time you read this comment...but it will say _"edited..."_ and then some indication of the time the edit happened.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to associate the inventory level of the ingredients (which you have as your double variables), with the order id of the ingredient (which is the result you want at the end).

One solution would be to use an Ingredient class that might look something like this:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public double InventoryLevel { get; set; }
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could have a list of ingredients, rather than doubles, order them by their inventory level, and get the lowest stocked ingredient.

```
// make your list of ingredients with order ids, and inventory levels
var ingredients = new List<Ingredient>
{
    new Ingredient {OrderId = "Ingredient1", InventoryLevel = 10.0},
    new Ingredient {OrderId = "Ingredient2", InventoryLevel = 2.0},
    new Ingredient {OrderId = "Ingredient3", InventoryLevel = 15.0},
    new Ingredient {OrderId = "Ingredient4", InventoryLevel = 6.0}
};

// get the ingredient with the lowest inventory level
var lowestStockedIngredient = ingredients.OrderBy(i => i.InventoryLevel ).FirstOrDefault();

string orderId = lowestStockedIngredient.OrderId;
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you so much for taking the time.  I completely understand this :)

Comment: Just wanted to add that I implemented this and it was just, delicious.  Thanks to this I can now add a better system for automatic ordering.  Thank you again Erresen

Comment: No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the name of the variable, try `nameof(var)`, in this case `string orderId = nameof(orderValue);`

Otherwise, you might want to look into creating a custom class for your ingredients or using a `Dictionary<string, double>`.

edit:
A dictionary would achieve a similar result as using the custom Ingredient class.

```
var items = new Dictionary<string, double>()
{
    { "ingredient1", 2 },
    { "ingredient2", 4 },
    { "ingredient3", 5 },
    { "ingredient4", 1 },
};
var lowestIngredient = items.OrderBy(i => i.Value).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine($"{lowestIngredient.Key} {lowestIngredient.Value}");
```

Comment: How does this help the OP produce the name of the variable for the minimum value? If you want to propose a dictionary, how do you expect the OP to use that? Why do you think a dictionary is even a valid solution for their assignment?

Comment: You're right, looking up the `nameof()` of a list would just get the name of the list. I added an example of using a dictionary. Erresen's answer shows an example of using a custom class.